# Rails: csv error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

I have a csv file that contains 3000 rows and I'm getting an error of `CSV::MalformedCSVError: Missing or stray quote in line 1427`
but all the datas are well separated with a comma. I can't find the error on this line

```
"Anjou","(ANJ) Jean-Corbeil / Adultes - BD",2008-03-08 23:51:10,2,1,"Disponible","LV_Fiction A","","Philémon, l'arche du "A" /","","Fred,","","Dargaud,","Neuilly-sur-Seine ;","quc","c1976.","48 p. :","fre","","2205010301",""
```

seeds.rb

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach('file.csv') do |row|
 puts row[0]
 puts row[1]
 ...
end
```

Comment: `"Philémon, l'arche du "A" /"` seems to have unescaped quotation marks.

Comment: so if I do understand it's the "A" that causes problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
"Philémon, l'arche du "A" /"
```

This is your problem: the "A" is part of the string, but the quotes are not escaped, so it is read as:

```
"Philémon, l'arche du " - A - " /"
```

And the "A" part is not correct. Try escaping the quotes:

```
"Philémon, l'arche du \"A\" "
```